# What is the optimal batch size in django

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering that the optimal batch size while making bulk create in Django. I don't know the exact number of data. It might be millions or thousands. How can I decide the optimal batch size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more dependent on the database setup than Django. Because in the [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e41f9f94505f690525f16af8bd10e62e22bc0207/django/db/models/query.py#L1849) of `bulk_update`, a given list of objects is divided into batches, and then insert statements are created for each batch. The insert statements are then executed on the database. As a result, the batch's execution is handled by the database. If the `batch_size` is too large for your database configuration, you may experience performance issues and even errors.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update), by default it tries to do one query - which in most cases is fastest way to update. "Optimal" batch size depends on various factors: starting from type of database and its limits, through server performance, network(latency), ending on your code (for example: how much do you changes you make in objects).

If it's new project or you haven't noticed any issues with updates, I'd stick to default.